# Postfix : relay access denied

Tags: centos, postfix, outlook

Since I can't find a solution that works with my config, I lean on you guys to help me out with this.

I've installed postfix and dovecot on a CentOS server. Everything's running well. But when I try to send an e-mail from Outlook to tld that is not .com, server returns : **Relay access denied.**

Here's the result from the **postconf -n** command

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
home_mailbox = Maildir/
html_directory = no
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 104857600
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
message_size_limit = 20971520
mydestination = $myhostname, $mydomain, localhost, localhost.$mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtp_tls_loglevel = 3
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/mailserver.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/mailserver.pem
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

Here's the maillog error :

```
Nov 23 13:26:24 website_name postfix/smtpd[16391]: extract_addr: input: <mrm@website_name.com>
Nov 23 13:26:24 website_name postfix/smtpd[16391]: smtpd_check_addr: addr=mrm@website_name.com
Nov 23 13:26:24 website_name postfix/smtpd[16391]: ctable_locate: move existing entry key mrm@website_name.com
Nov 23 13:26:24 website_name postfix/smtpd[16391]: extract_addr: in: <mrm@website_name.com>, result: mrm@website_name.com
Nov 23 13:26:24 website_name postfix/smtpd[16391]: fsspace: .: block size 4096, blocks free 23679665
Nov 23 13:26:24 website_name postfix/smtpd[16391]: smtpd_check_queue: blocks 4096 avail 23679665 min_free 0 msg_size_limit 20971520
Nov 23 13:26:24 website_name postfix/smtpd[16391]: > unknown[178.193.xxx.xxx]: 250 2.1.0 Ok
Nov 23 13:26:24 website_name postfix/smtpd[16391]: < unknown[178.193.xxx.xxx]: RCPT TO:<webmaster@somehost.fr>
Nov 23 13:26:24 website_name postfix/smtpd[16391]: extract_addr: input: <webmaster@somehost.fr>
Nov 23 13:26:24 website_name postfix/smtpd[16391]: smtpd_check_addr: addr=webmaster@somehost.fr
Nov 23 13:26:24 website_name postfix/smtpd[16391]: ctable_locate: move existing entry key webmaster@somehost.fr
Nov 23 13:26:24 website_name postfix/smtpd[16391]: extract_addr: in: <webmaster@somehost.fr>, result: webmaster@somehost.fr
Nov 23 13:26:24 website_name postfix/smtpd[16391]: >>> START Recipient address RESTRICTIONS <<<
Nov 23 13:26:24 website_name postfix/smtpd[16391]: generic_checks: name=permit_sasl_authenticated
Nov 23 13:26:24 website_name postfix/smtpd[16391]: generic_checks: name=permit_sasl_authenticated status=0
Nov 23 13:26:24 website_name postfix/smtpd[16391]: generic_checks: name=reject_unauth_destination
Nov 23 13:26:24 website_name postfix/smtpd[16391]: reject_unauth_destination: webmaster@somehost.fr
Nov 23 13:26:24 website_name postfix/smtpd[16391]: permit_auth_destination: webmaster@somehost.fr
Nov 23 13:26:24 website_name postfix/smtpd[16391]: ctable_locate: leave existing entry key webmaster@somehost.fr
Nov 23 13:26:24 website_name postfix/smtpd[16391]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[178.193.xxx.xxx]: 554 5.7.1 <webmaster@somehost.fr>: Relay access denied; from=<mrm@website_name.com> to=<webmaster@somehost.fr> proto=ESMTP helo=<[192.168.1.38]>
Nov 23 13:26:24 website_name postfix/smtpd[16391]: generic_checks: name=reject_unauth_destination status=2
Nov 23 13:26:24 website_name postfix/smtpd[16391]: > unknown[178.193.xxx.xxx]: 554 5.7.1 <webmaster@somehost.fr>: Relay access denied
Nov 23 13:26:24 website_name postfix/smtpd[16391]: smtp_get: EOF
```

What's wrong with this?

**UPDATE : added to main.cf**

```
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous noplaintext
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = $smtpd_sasl_security_options
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
```

**UPDATE : EHLO**

```
EHLO mail.perflux.com
250-perflux.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 20971520
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
```

**UPDATE : log**

```
: connection established
: master_notify: status 0
: name_mask: resource
: name_mask: software
: connect from unknown[remoteIP]
: match_list_match: unknown: no match
: match_list_match: remoteIP: no match
: match_list_match: unknown: no match
: match_list_match: remoteIP: no match
: match_hostname: unknown ~? 127.0.0.0/8
: match_hostaddr: remoteIP ~? 127.0.0.0/8
: match_hostname: unknown ~? 195.70.x.x/24
: match_hostaddr: remoteIP ~? 195.70.x.x/24
: match_hostname: unknown ~? [::1]/128
: match_hostaddr: remoteIP ~? [::1]/128
: match_hostname: unknown ~? [fe80::%eth0]/64
: match_hostaddr: remoteIP ~? [fe80::%eth0]/64
: match_list_match: unknown: no match
: match_list_match: remoteIP: no match
: send attr request = connect
: send attr ident = smtp:remoteIP
: private/anvil: wanted attribute: status
: input attribute name: status
: input attribute value: 0
: private/anvil: wanted attribute: count
: input attribute name: count
: input attribute value: 1
: private/anvil: wanted attribute: rate
: input attribute name: rate
: input attribute value: 2
: private/anvil: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
: input attribute name: (end)
: > unknown[remoteIP]: 220 domain.com ESMTP Postfix
: < unknown[remoteIP]: EHLO [192.168.1.38]
: > unknown[remoteIP]: 250-domain.com
: > unknown[remoteIP]: 250-PIPELINING
: > unknown[remoteIP]: 250-SIZE 20971520
: > unknown[remoteIP]: 250-VRFY
: > unknown[remoteIP]: 250-ETRN
: match_list_match: unknown: no match
: match_list_match: remoteIP: no match
: > unknown[remoteIP]: 250-STARTTLS
: > unknown[remoteIP]: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
: > unknown[remoteIP]: 250-8BITMIME
: > unknown[remoteIP]: 250 DSN
: < unknown[remoteIP]: STARTTLS
: > unknown[remoteIP]: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
: setting up TLS connection from unknown[remoteIP]
: unknown[remoteIP]: TLS cipher list "ALL:!EXPORT:!LOW:+RC4:@STRENGTH"
: auto_clnt_open: connected to private/tlsmgr
: send attr request = seed
: send attr size = 32
: private/tlsmgr: wanted attribute: status
: input attribute name: status
: input attribute value: 0
: private/tlsmgr: wanted attribute: seed
: input attribute name: seed
: input attribute value: 7FfGXFU+Rpalr27a4Gy4AcFT7UY0uKwxVopJXiqNiJQ=
: private/tlsmgr: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
: input attribute name: (end)
: SSL_accept:before/accept initialization […]
: SSL_accept:SSLv3 read client hello A
: SSL_accept:SSLv3 write server hello A
: SSL_accept:SSLv3 write certificate A
: SSL_accept:SSLv3 write server done A […]
: SSL_accept:SSLv3 flush data […]
: SSL_accept:SSLv3 read client key exchange A […]
: SSL_accept:SSLv3 read finished A
: SSL_accept:SSLv3 write change cipher spec A
: SSL_accept:SSLv3 write finished A […]
: SSL_accept:SSLv3 flush data
: Anonymous TLS connection established from unknown[remoteIP]: TLSv1 with cipher DES-CBC3-SHA (168/168 bits)
: xsasl_dovecot_server_create: SASL service=smtp, realm=(null)
: name_mask: noanonymous
: xsasl_dovecot_server_mech_filter: keep mechanism: PLAIN
: xsasl_dovecot_server_mech_filter: keep mechanism: LOGIN
: < unknown[remoteIP]: EHLO [192.168.1.38]
: > unknown[remoteIP]: 250-domain.com
: > unknown[remoteIP]: 250-PIPELINING
: > unknown[remoteIP]: 250-SIZE 20971520
```

And it stops...

Comment: looks like you didn't configure SASL authentication - http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html (in your case read the chapter about dovecot sasl)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried to configure the SASL authentication before but it didn't work. When I try to send an e-mail, outlooks returns "Connection to the server failed or was dropped" and nothing much in the maillog... hmmm.

Comment: Can you explain how did you tried to configure the SASL authentication? What made you think it didn't work?

Comment: I configured postfix to allow SASL authentication (as you can see in the update). Now, when I try to send an e-mail from a remote client, the connection keeps loading forever before saying "Connection was dropped out".

Comment: Is dovecot started?

Comment: Yes, dovecot is running and delivers new emails perfectly :/

Comment: First of all, can you update ticket with server output for EHLO command?

Comment: Please include NON-VERBOSE logs of a complete SMTP transaction.

Comment: Is /etc/postfix/mailserver.pem correctly generated?

Comment: Ticket updated with EHLO command @ kworr.

Comment: mailserver.pem is correctly generated too @ Laurentiu

Comment: Updated ticket with new log

Answer (score 1):

Unless this system is purely internal, setting

```
smtpd_tls_security_level = encrypt
```

will ensure that it never, ever receives internet mail.

If instead you meant to secure user submission, you need to configure the ***submission*** service as commented out in the master.cf file.

Submission occurs on port 587, not port 25, and should always be secured and authenticated, as per [**RFC6409**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6409)

Comment: Thanks for the help. So I've configured the submission service (inet), set smtpd_tls_security_level to **may** and smptd_tls_auth_only to **no**. It's still doesn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

For a start you could add the IP address of your workstation to `mynetworks`. For example:

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 178.193.xxx.xxx
```

If everything works ok then try to debug why SASL authentication does not work, if you need help you should post maillog after SASL was enabled.

Comment: No. This is a very bad practice in general, as you have no control over what comes in from that IP.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that would be even easier to add all tlds to mydestination. But I'm trying to solve the problem with good practices only ^^

Comment: You got it all wrong. I suggested that just for debugging purposes and not as a final solution. On the other hand I suspect that your client is not properly configured to use authentication.

Comment: It works and yes, the problem is the authentication

Answer (score 0):

Try #2:

I was right stating that your server refuses to authenticate. Now I see that the problem has layers:

1. You haven't added your sending host to $mynetworks (you can check it with `postconf -d | grep mynetworks`) and as such server will accept mail from you only if you will authenticate to it.
2. As you had specified `smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes` authentication should proceed only over encrypted connection.
3. Your client starts encrypted connection but... your log is over. What happened next? Is there anything about authentication errors on other logs?

I also know that sasl by default authenticates users to its internal database. But you haven't specified your authentication source also. The good guide on setting Postfix/SASL/Dovecot auth is at http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html#server_dovecot_comm, try checking it out.

Comment: He already has that set.

Comment: I know (TM), but if he is connecting on non-encrypted port so server would not even say about possible authentication and treat user unauthenticated. And he configured authentication the way it would only permit authenticated users to send mail.